# "Брызгает" или "брызжет"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее сказать: "брызгает" или "брызжет"? Или это два разных процесса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это две формы настоящего времени глагола брызгать. Отличаются оттенками значений. Форма **брызжет** и ее приставочные образования употребляется обычно в прямом значении: "быстро отбрасывать или выбрасывать мелкие частицы жидкости"(брызжет дождь. фонтан, водопад; брызжут слезы,кровь). За вариантом **брызгать - брызгает** закрепилось узкое значение "опрыскивать, окроплять какой-нибудь жидкостью" :побрызгать волосы духами, обрызгают водой...